# Value of element changed twice by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on a stat app and using functions a lot to make it easy. Because there's like stats for different positions, and then different stats like touchdowns. Working on the quarterback section, because after that it's repetition. The problem is this... When I first click a stat, let's say touchdowns, it works fine. I use my back arrow, go to let's say completions, it still works fine. Then I have a next button because not every player can be displayed at once. It loads the right thing but then changes the stat and I don't know why. If I try another stat, it'll change it twice when I click next, so I assume it's a loop error

I tried looking over the code and asking Reddit. No reply

```
var Players = [];
var list = [];
var count = 0;

// So the code below organizes players by stats. 
// For example, if you call touchdowns, it'll organize from most touchdowns to lowest.
function myFunction(Position, Stat, startingpoint, endingpoint) {
  readRecords(Position, {}, function(records) {
    var temp = 0;
    var name = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
      for (var j = i + 1; j < records.length; j++) {
        if ((records[i])[Stat] < records[j][Stat]) {
          temp = records[i][Stat];
          name = records[i].Player;
          (records[i])[Stat] = (records[j])[Stat];
          records[i].Player = records[j].Player;
          records[j][Stat] = temp;
          records[j].Player = name;
        }
      }
      insertItem(Players, i, (records[i]).Player + " : " + (records[i])[Stat] + " " + Stat + "\n");
    }
    for (var k = startingpoint; k < endingpoint; k++) {
      appendItem(list, Players[k]);
      var x = list.join(" ");
    }

    setText("label2", x);
    for (var l = endingpoint; l >= startingpoint; l--) {
      removeItem(list, Players[l]);
    }
  });

}

// So I made this part cause I thought let's say I had 60 players, and 20 players per page. 
// How would the program know if I wanna see players 0-20 or 20-40 if I click previous? 
// It's to organize that based on a count variable that changes when you click back and forward.
onEvent("button1", "click", function() {
    count = count + 1;
});

onEvent("button2", "click", function() {
    count = count - 1;
});

// And this was supposed to call back my original function to organize stats when I click the next or previous button. 
// Guess this is where my problem is.
function callback(Stats) {
    count = 0;
    setText("label2", "");
    onEvent("button1", "click", function() {
        if (count == 1) {
            myFunction("Quarterbacks", Stats, 40, 69);
        }
    });

    onEvent("button2", "click", function() {
        if (count == 0) {
            myFunction("Quarterbacks", Stats, 0, 40);
        }
    });
}

// Quarterback stats
onEvent("QuarterBackmenu", "change", function() {
    setScreen("OffenseStatScreen");

    if (getText("QuarterBackmenu") == "Touchdowns") {
        setText("label2", "");
        myFunction("Quarterbacks", "Touchdowns", 0, 40);
        setText("QuarterBackmenu", "Quarterback");
        callback("Touchdowns");
    } else if ((getText("QuarterBackmenu") == "Completions")) {
        setText("label2", "");
        myFunction("Quarterbacks", "Completions", 0, 40);
        setText("QuarterBackmenu", "Quarterback");
        callback("Completions");
    }
});
```

So I expect it to display the proper stats in order. When I first choose a stat on quarterback, it works. I choose another one, it works, but when I click next, it displays the right stat but then quickly changes? If I try again, it changes twice? 
And here's a link to use my program and see. So go to offense, quarterback, choose a stat, use the back arrow, check another stat and then click next

https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/cHpi9aqp6p_lYtDH3EErcethc2KSxhjXJVeJ3mHZ1LQ

Comment: Use ``` to wrap your code please

Comment: Please take the time and format the code probably. As is, no one will be able to help.

Comment: @kit or just indent it 4 spaces

Comment: Okay, I'll organize it better

Comment: Okay I'll try I guess. Not sure exactly how, but I'll try

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Limit the included code to what's necessary to reproduce. Properly indented code is significantly easier to reason about.

Comment: How about you format your code in an editor, indent it all by an extra 4 spaces, then paste it

Comment: You can use a beautifier like beautifier.io to format your code for you.

Comment: It'll be hard to get help if you don't format and simplify your code since people aren't familiar with what you're trying to achieve. Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: in `callback` which gets called all over the place, you add event listeners to button1 and button2 clicks - the problem may be that you're using `addEventListener` (can't see what **your** function called `onEvent` is) - if that's the case, you're adding more and more event listeners to the one button click, therefore, each click does multiple things, more and more as you go along

Comment: How do I fix it Jaromanda?

Comment: by changes to your logic - however, I don't understand the logic, I don't know what your code is supposed to be doing, I don't know why the button events should change, I just know that you're probably adding multiple listeners to click events which is causing your issues

Comment: Oh for the love of Eich, who made this into a runnable snippet!! and didn't even bother using the tidy function - I've fixed the indentation now - including missing `}})` - at least it's readable

Comment: So the original myfunction organizes the players by stat, depending on what they choose. My callback uses variables so you know what page of stats you're on. So let's say I'm displaying players 20-40 and I click next. I used variables so it knows if I'm viewing players 20-40 or 40-60, and it can properly display the next batch of players. But my original myfunction is when you choose a stat, this calls it back for when you click the button. I guess I can add an event handler in each if statement

Comment: `I can add an event handler in each if statement` - and then you'll **still** have multiple click handlers - you need to remove handlers if you don't want them any more - again, it's hard to say what you want, but you definitely don't want to keep adding click handlers on every click

Comment: I'll organize it a bit better, or try to. Still new to this, just a high school student doing a project

Comment: Uhh, I hope that helped you a bit

Comment: Thank you Dave!!! You solved my problem, i wanna understand how it works now. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call the function `callback` you are adding additional event handlers.

```
function callback(Stats) {
    count = 0;
    setText("label2", "");
    onEvent("button1", "click", function( ) {
        if (count == 1) {
            myFunction("Quarterbacks", Stats, 40, 69);
        }
    });

    onEvent("button2", "click", function( ) {
        if (count == 0) {
            myFunction("Quarterbacks", Stats, 0, 40);
        }
    });
}
```

You probably just need to move the `onEvent` handlers outside of that function, with some way of passing the Stats to it:

```
var Stats;

function callback(stats) {
    count = 0;
    setText("label2", "");
    Stats = stats
}

onEvent("button1", "click", function( ) {
    if (count == 1) {
        myFunction("Quarterbacks", Stats, 40, 69);
    }
});

onEvent("button2", "click", function( ) {
    if (count == 0) {
        myFunction("Quarterbacks", Stats, 0, 40);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of code missing, but glancing over it I can see an anti-pattern that might be the source of your problems:

```
function callback(Stats) {

    count = 0;
    setText("label2", "");

    onEvent("button1", "click", function() {
        if (count == 1) {
            myFunction("Quarterbacks", Stats, 40, 69);
        }
    });

    onEvent("button2", "click", function() {
        if (count == 0) {
            myFunction("Quarterbacks", Stats, 0, 40);
        }
    });
}
```

Every time the `callback` function is called, it creates two brand new event-handlers for `button1` and `button2`. You call `callback` many, many times in your code, so as the program runs you're probably ending up with hundreds of these handlers all fighting to run `myFunction("Quarter...`

But there are also other problems with the code. It would be a good exercise for you to name your functions based on what they are supposed to do. For example, I have no idea what `myFunction` or `callback` do.

As a start, write a small specification document that outlines, just briefly, what each part of your program is supposed to do. From there you can determine which functions to write, what they should be called, and at what point in the life-cycle of the program.

I get the feeling that the code has so-far been growing organically without any organisation to it. Nothing wrong with that, but perhaps it's time to add some structure and discipline to it.